# Android googleMap Map does not show, only grid, sometimes

Tags: java, android, google-maps

So, I have been working on getting this up and running for some time now. Problem is I have my map key from Google placed correctly in main.xml, but I can't seem to get a provider information as the map does not display at all. I have run it a couple of times and the fail us at the same place. I tried to debug and noticed that there is a provider string returned, however, after that a null.

The code fails at

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    locationManager
            .requestLocationUpdates(getBestProvider(), 1000, 1, this);
}
```

with the following error message.

```
08-20 05:14:43.573: E/AndroidRuntime(239): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
08-20 05:14:43.583: E/AndroidRuntime(239): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {com.shawnbe.mallfinder/com.shawnbe.mallfinder.MallFinderActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-20 05:14:43.583: E/AndroidRuntime(239):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2950)
08-20 05:14:43.583: E/AndroidRuntime(239):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2965)
08-20 05:14:43.583: E/AndroidRuntime(239):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2516)
08-20 05:14:43.583: E/AndroidRuntime(239):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2200(ActivityThread.java:119)
08-20 05:14:43.583: E/AndroidRuntime(239):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1863)
08-20 05:14:43.583: E/AndroidRuntime(239):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-20 05:14:43.583: E/AndroidRuntime(239):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
08-20 05:14:43.583: E/AndroidRuntime(239):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)
08-20 05:14:43.583: E/AndroidRuntime(239):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-20 05:14:43.583: E/AndroidRuntime(239):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
08-20 05:14:43.583: E/AndroidRuntime(239):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
08-20 05:14:43.583: E/AndroidRuntime(239):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
08-20 05:14:43.583: E/AndroidRuntime(239):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-20 05:14:43.583: E/AndroidRuntime(239): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-20 05:14:43.583: E/AndroidRuntime(239):  at com.shawnbe.mallfinder.MallFinderActivity.onResume(MallFinderActivity.java:61)
08-20 05:14:43.583: E/AndroidRuntime(239):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1149)
08-20 05:14:43.583: E/AndroidRuntime(239):  at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:3763)
08-20 05:14:43.583: E/AndroidRuntime(239):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2937)
08-20 05:14:43.583: E/AndroidRuntime(239):  ... 12 more
```

Occasionally, the code seems launches the grid but no map. While on other runs, it simply fails out.

Below is my activity code.

```
package com.shawnbe.mallfinder;

import java.util.List;

import com.google.android.maps.GeoPoint;
import com.google.android.maps.MapActivity;
import com.google.android.maps.MapController;
import com.google.android.maps.MapView;
import com.google.android.maps.Overlay;
import com.google.android.maps.OverlayItem;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.location.Criteria;
import android.location.Location;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MallFinderActivity extends MapActivity implements
        android.location.LocationListener {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

    private MapController mapController;
    private MapView mapView;
    private android.location.LocationManager locationManager;
    private GeoPoint currentPoint;
    private Location currentLocation = null;
    private TextView latituteField;
    private TextView longitudeField;
    private String bestProvider;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        MapView mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapView);
        mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        Location location;
        //getBestProvider();
        if(bestProvider !=null)
        location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(bestProvider);

        List<Overlay> mapOverlays = mapView.getOverlays();
        Drawable drawable = this.getResources().getDrawable(
                R.drawable.androidmarker);
        MapItemizedOverlay itemizedoverlay = new MapItemizedOverlay(drawable,
                this);
        LocalGeoPoints loc = new LocalGeoPoints();
        for (OverlayItem a : loc.overlayitems) {
            itemizedoverlay.addOverlay(a);
        }
        mapOverlays.add(itemizedoverlay);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        locationManager
                .requestLocationUpdates(getBestProvider(), 1000, 1, this);
    }

    public void getLastLocation() {
        String provider = getBestProvider();
        currentLocation = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
        if (currentLocation != null) {
            setCurrentLocation(currentLocation);
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Location not yet acquired", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show();
        }
    }

    public void animateToCurrentLocation() {
        if (currentPoint != null) {
            mapController.animateTo(currentPoint);
        }
    }

    public String getBestProvider() {
        locationManager = (android.location.LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
        criteria.setPowerRequirement(Criteria.NO_REQUIREMENT);
        criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.NO_REQUIREMENT);
        bestProvider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, false);

        return bestProvider;
    }

    public void setCurrentLocation(Location location) {
        int currLatitude = (int) (location.getLatitude() * 1E6);
        int currLongitude = (int) (location.getLongitude() * 1E6);
        currentPoint = new GeoPoint(currLatitude, currLongitude);
        currentLocation = new Location("");
        currentLocation.setLatitude(currentPoint.getLatitudeE6() / 1e6);
        currentLocation.setLongitude(currentPoint.getLongitudeE6() / 1e6);
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {

        return false;
    }

    /* Remove the locationlistener updates when Activity is paused */
    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        locationManager.removeUpdates(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        int lat = (int) (location.getLatitude());
        int lng = (int) (location.getLongitude());
        latituteField.setText(String.valueOf(lat));
        longitudeField.setText(String.valueOf(lng));
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Enabled new provider " + provider,
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Disabled provider " + provider,
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

And below is my  main.xml ccomplete with the key I obtained from the google map registeration site.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <FrameLayout 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <com.google.android.maps.MapView
        android:id="@+id/mapView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:apiKey="0steid872FeGgae0eO2Dhdyei37sFPHG65t7N6XA"/>
    </FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

[image: The image below is all I get]

Comment: [See this link](http://www.letsnurture-review.info/technology/how-to-get-google-map-private-key-and-use-it-to-export-an-android-application/) for more information.

Comment: I have the key correctly set up and all.

Comment: I think this error would occur only because of wrong key.

Comment: but I have the right key generated using the MD5 fingerprint from my signing the app. What else do I need to do apart from add it to the main.xml file before running it?

Comment: Hello? Anyone out there able to help me solve this problem?

Comment: Please remove your Google Maps API key that you've posted IMMEDIATELY. People can abuse it very easily.

Comment: Don't worry, that is not the real Key. Thanks though! :)

Comment: Okk you should follow [Using Google Maps in Android](http://mobiforge.com/developing/story/using-google-maps-android). Here in this link you can get all you want. Thanks

Comment: Have you tried it on an actual active device or in the emulator?

Comment: getBestProvider() call is commented out in onCreate(). That means locationManager is never initialized. Can you fix the code?

Comment: @Kobojunkie: do you have create the mapkey with your personal keystore for the apk publication or with the keystore for debug?

Comment: @Kobojunkie: can u please post ur manifest file?

Answer (score 4):

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/mapkey - official information, what to do.

Step by step.

1) Create keystore

2) Generating hash MD5 from your keystore

3) Sign in here :  https://developers.google.com/android/maps-api-signup

4) Add key to your application

Good luck!

Comment: I already did that about 5 times so far and still nothing. I have the samd MD5 Hash and still using the same google key but it's the same

Answer (score 2):

In `onCreate` you should init `locationManager` field. Move

```
locationManager = (android.location.LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
```

string from `getBestProvider()` method to your onCreate()

Look at your stacktrace. You have only one place where NPE can potentially occurred

```
. . . 
08-20 05:14:43.583: E/AndroidRuntime(239): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-20 05:14:43.583: E/AndroidRuntime(239):  at com.shawnbe.mallfinder.MallFinderActivity.onResume(MallFinderActivity.java:61)
08-20 05:14:43.583: E/AndroidRuntime(239):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1149)
```

Comment: If you look at the code example there, you see that I am already trying to instantiate the locationManager object in the Oncreate() method

Answer (score 2):

The reason you are getting a NullPointer is that you never set `locationManager` before you use it in `onResume()`.

`onCreate()` is going to get called where you have `getBestProvider()` commented out.  Then `onResume()` gets called and that uses locationManager.  Although you have yet another even more complicated situation here.  I'll see if I can walk through procedurally what code will execute in onResume()...

1. super.onResume()
2. locationManager.requestLocationUpdates() <-- it'll probably go look up this method and get you a null pointer... we'll continue if locationManager weren't null
3. locationManager = (android.location.LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE); <-- now you're changing the object referenced from step 2...

If I were you I'd simplify things, only set the locationManager in `onCreate()` (as a general programming practice you want to limit the number of side effects in methods, what I mean is in `getBestProvider()`, you should just return the best provider, and try not to do anything else to your state, or you get crazy unexpected things outside that method).  If you're still getting some madness, I would just put that first line of `getBestProvider()` in `onResume()`

```
protected void onResume() 
{
    super.onResume();
    locationManager = (android.location.LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(getBestProvider(), 1000, 1, this);
}
```

You probably don't want to leave it that way, but it will ensure that your problem is that locationManager is null in `onResume()`

Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you initialize it before using it.

```
locationManager = (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
```

Comment: locationManager is null in a few places where you try to use it. make sure you initialize it before using it in those places (near the top of onCreate()). Also, you get the grid because its likely you don't have an internet connection to download the actual maps.... Make sure you give your manifest the internet permission as well!

Answer (score 1):

if you have valid map key then check whether you are getting an instance of locationManager  into  onResume i guess you have to instantiate location manager in onResume() .

```
 locationManager = (android.location.LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
```

Comment: [here](http://mobiforge.com/developing/story/using-google-maps-android) is tutorial to get map api key.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to center the map view and set a reasonable zoom level. Otherwise, the map view may show some random area.

```
mapView.setCenter(
    new GeoPoint((int)(25.76032 * 1E6),  (int)(-80.213928 * 1E6)));
//Set a reasonable zoom level
mapView.setZoom(12);
```

Answer (score 1):

NullPointerException is because of you are accessing null object of locationmanager.

Answer (score 1):

create apk in release mode and run this apk file,because google map will display when apk in release mode.

Answer (score 1):

Please Update your Google map API key, previous API key was expired so in this circumstance you are not able to see Google Map.  https://developers.google.com/android/maps-api-signup

Answer (score 0):

probabilly there is also a mapkey problem:

if you run your application in debug mode for testing, you have to create a mapkey using the default keystore for debug (for example on linux you can find it at ~/.android/debug.keystore) and insert this mapkey in code and use it untill you debug your app.

if you want to create an apk and run it (for example to publish your apk on market), you have to create a new mapkey using your personal keystore, and change it from your code before to generate the apk

Answer (score 0):

The MAP API requires a valid key to work properly.

To get the api key for your application you need to follow the steps given below.

1. Generate the certification fingerprint of your application using the keytool command.

   keytool -list -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore
   Example: 94:1E:43:49:87:73:BB:E6:A6:88:D7:20:F1:8E:B5:98
2. Using the fingerprint value you can generate the map api key from the link given below

   https://developers.google.com/android/maps-api-signup

Note:

1. when you want to release the application, The same maps api key can't be used. you must use the release keystore instead of the debug keystore (.android/debug.keystore). Generate the fingerprint using the command given above and use it to generate the maps api key for production use.
2. The keytool binary can be found in your system jre bin folder.

> C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_06\jre\bin

Answer (score 0):

locationManager is null, there is no discussion about it, did you specify it in manifest.xml?